# Returning a column to use in for loop for naive-bayes in R

Tags: r, for-loop, naivebayes

I'm doing a naive-bayes algorithm in R. The main goal is to predict a variable's value. But in this specific task, I'm trying to see which column is better at predicting it.
This is an **example of what works** (but in the real dataset doing it manually isn't an option):

```
   library(naivebayes)
   data("mtcars")
   mtcars$vsLog <- as.logical(as.integer(mtcars$vs))
   mtcars_train <- mtcars[1:20,]
   mtcars_test <- mtcars[20:32,]
   car_model <- naive_bayes( data=mtcars_train, vsLog ~ mpg )
   predictions <- predict(car_model,mtcars_test)
```

What I'm having trouble with is performing a for loop, in which the model takes one column at a time, and save how good each model did at predicting the values.
I've looked at different ways to input the columns as something I can iterate over, but couldn't make it work. 
My minimum reproducible example of my problem is:

```
library(naivebayes)
data("mtcars")
mtcars$vsLog <- as.logical(as.integer(mtcars$vs))
mtcars_train <- mtcars[1:20,]
mtcars_test <- mtcars[20:32,]

for (j in 1:ncol(mtcars)) {
car_model <- naive_bayes( data=mtcars_train, vsLog ~ mtcars_train[,j] )
predictions[j] <- predict(car_model,mtcars_test)
}
```

The problem is **how to replace mpg in the first example with something I can loop over**. Things I've tried: mtcars_train$mpg , unlist( mtcars_train[,j] ) , colnames .
I really tried googling this, I hope it's not too silly of a question.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful. If you want to use a `for` loop, you can use `seq_along` with the names of your columns you want to loop through in your dataset. You can use `reformulate` to create a formula, which would you `vsLog` in your example, as well as the jth item in your column names. In this example, you can store your `predict` results in a list. Perhaps this might translate to your real dataset.

```
pred_lst <- list()

mtcars_names <- names(mtcars_train)

for (j in seq_along(mtcars_names)) {
  car_model <- naive_bayes(reformulate(mtcars_names[j], "vsLog"), data=mtcars_train)
  pred_lst[[j]] <- predict(car_model, mtcars_test)
}
```

Comment: This is correct... I'd heard about seq_along but reformulate... There's not much info concerning that function but it's what I needed. I couldn't get the pred_lst to work, but used a vector instead.
Thanks man